# WPF Custom Web Browser Firewall Block

Tags: wpf, browser, webbrowser-control, firewall, windows-firewall

I was created wpf custom web browser but i can't use this browser on new computer which has active windows firewall.

I tested to create rules with **ie, firefox, safari, chrome**.. it all worked but i created rule for my app, it's not working..

How can i solve this connection block problem? Do you have any idea how can we create an exception for custom web browser on windows firewall?

**Note:** I tried to add my wpf program to firewall (incoming/outgoing) but never worked.